# Process Explorer - Longer Resource Utilization Timeline

Tags: process-explorer

I want to set process explorer so I can view resource utilization over a 1 - 2 hour period. Meaning, I can let it do its thing and then come back later to view the capture.

Answer (score 1):

[Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744567%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is used to track the various performance counters over longer periods of time. You can set the graph elements sample rate and duration (how long the X axis shows).